# loop through variables for plots in R

Tags: r, for-loop

Would like to iterate through a forloop with a set of six variables (metgoal1.pct, metgoal2.pct... metgoal6.pct) to create plots in R. I'd like to replace the metgoal3.pct in the plot and point functions in code below with a metgoalj.pct (or something appropriate) and put a for (j in 1:6){} around it.

Tried using eval, assign, or paste but am not getting the right combination. And if there's a better way to do this with an apply function, am all ears.

```
      jpeg(paste("metgoal",j,".jpg"))
      plot(user_day_trunc,metgoal3.pct,type="n",xlab="day",ylab="accuracy")
      for (i in 1:length(finalusers)){
        points(user_day_trunc[user_id==finalusers[i]],metgoal3.pct[user_id==finalusers[i]],type="p", pch=17, col=colors[i])
      }
      title(paste("Goal ",j," - ",goals [j])) 
      dev.off()
```

Comment: really not sure what you're asking, does `for (i in 1:length(finalusers)){x <- get(sprintf('metgoal%s.pct', i)); points(user_day_trunc[user_id==finalusers[i]], x[user_id==finalusers[i]], ...)}` work ?

Comment: yes this works, thanks!